# Truncating a BINARY column in MySQL using ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, binary-data, truncate, alter-table, truncation

I have a MySQL table `t` with over 150 million rows. One of the columns (`c`) was a `VARCHAR(64)` containing a 64-digit hexadecimal number. To save space and make things faster, I wanted to decode the hex and turn it into a `BINARY(32)` column.

My plan was to use three queries:

1. `ALTER TABLE t CHANGE c c BINARY(64) NOT NULL;`
2. `UPDATE t SET c=UNHEX(c);`
3. `ALTER TABLE t CHANGE c c BINARY(32) NOT NULL;`

The first 2 worked perfectly, but on the 3rd query I'm getting the error:

`#1265 - Data truncated for column 'c' at row 1`

I understand that I am truncating data, that's exactly what I want. I want to get rid of the 32 `0x00` bytes at the end of the `BINARY(64)` to turn it into a `BINARY(32)`.

Things I've tried:

- `UPDATE t SET c=LEFT(c, 32);` did not seem to do anything at all.
- Using `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

To get around the `#1265 - Data truncated for column ...` error you must remove the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` flag from the global `sql_mode` variable.

The query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';` gave me:

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

So I ran this query:

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

For safety, I will re-enable strict mode after I'm done truncating columns.

Comment: this solution worked for me, thanks lot @Jesbus